# Table html with Twig & Yaml in Grav

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml, grav

I can not display the content under each title as an html table
**Yaml** :

```
table:
    -
        title: Test
        content:
            -
                value: 'test1'
            -
                value: 'test2'
            -
               value: 'test3'
     -
        title: ok
        content:
            -
                value: 'ok1'
            -
                value: 'ok2'
            -
                value: 'ok3'
     -
        title: abc
        content:
            -
                value: 'abc1'
            -
                value: 'abc2'
            -
                value: 'abc3'
```

**Twig :**

```
<table>         
            <thead>
                {% for item in page.header.table %}
                    <th>{{item.title}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for item in (page.header.table.0.content) %}
                <tr>

                        <td>{{item.value}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}   
            </tbody>          
        </table>
```

We must take a value of each content in each loop but I can not.
how to do in the table to have each content below its title ?

Comment: Do you have any relationship between title and it's content?

Answer (score 0):

I would try following in twig.

```
    <table>         
        <thead>
            {% for item in page.header.table %}
                <th>{{ item.title }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in (page.header.table) %}
               <tr>
               {% for content in item.content %}
                  <td>{{ content.value }}</td>
               {% endfor %}   
               </tr>
            {% endfor %}   
        </tbody>          
    </table
```

Using Multiple loops:

```
{% for item in (page.header.table) %}
    <tr>
    {% for content in item.content.0 %}
        <td>{{ content.value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}   
    {% for content in item.content.1 %}
        <td>{{ content.value }}</td>
    {% endfor %}   
    ...
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: is incorrect, everything is in the first <tr>.there is no other, to make a real table

Comment: I have Updated the answer.
The first for-loop will create number trs matching with the header titles.
The second loop will create content inside the tr.

Comment: It does not show what I want. Currently it shows Test ok abc, line next test1 test2 test3. I want to do Test ok abc, line next test1 ok1 abc1, next line test2 ok2 abc2 ...

Comment: That's why I have asked a question in a comment with your questions above.
What relation do you have between title and content? There must have to be some logic by which you can tell this title has these contents.

Comment: Yes sorry, the content of each title must be in column. The content must be below its title. We must find content [0] .value [0], content [1] .value [0], content [2] .value [0], in the first <tr> <td> for example

Comment: Then you have no choice but to do multiple for loops. 
Or you could build an array in PHP and use that array to loop through values.

Comment: how to do with multiple loop? could you show me please :( ?

Comment: This is just an idea, you have to modify based on your page array.
You haven't posted your page array but you mentioned that content[0] is an array of values.